# WPF Scroll View Delema

Tags: wpf, layout, scrollviewer

I've created a `UserControl` that contains a `ScrollViewer` panel that contains a data bounds `ItemsControl`.  When I add this `UserControl` into a `Grid`'s cell in the parent `Window`, the `ScrollViewer` expands to contain all of the items in the `ItemsControl` rather than constraining to the dimensions of the cell. Because of this, it won't scroll the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had my layout a little bit messed up.  Somehow I had a `ListBox` inside a `ScrollView` and so the two `ScrollViewers` messed each other up.

Sorry; WPF is very new to me.  Still getting a feel for it.

Answer (score 0):

A little more code would be helpful to see exactly what you are doing...

One thing to check is the "HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" (or "VerticalScrollBarVisibility" depending on orientation) property of the ScrollViewer, it should default to "Auto", but in your user control this may be getting overridden at a higher level in the visual tree; try setting it explicitly:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```